# How do I call a filter with one argument on several variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

i have a table of object:

```
[{"id": 11,
  "firstName": "Henry", 
  "lastName": "Durand", 
  "ManageList": { "id": 111, "lastName": "Coco"
                  "id": 112, "lastName": "Cocou"
                }
  "id": 12,
  "firstName": "John", 
  "lastName": "Durorn", 
  "ManageList": { "id": 121, "lastName": "Ceicol"
                  "id": 122, "lastName": "Cunoe"
                }
}]
```

I want to do a quick search by an input:

```
<input type="search" ng-model="filterSearch" />
```

And then i would like to filter ONLY on id, firstName and lastName (not the id or lastName of the ManageList).

```
ng-repeat="manager in managers | filter: filterSearch"
```

This filter watch everything, including ManageList.
is it possible to do something like:

```
ng-repeat="manager in managers | filter: {firstName:filterSearch || lastName:filterSearch || id:filtersearch}"
```

Comment: Take a look a this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1aFTAWDJUjtGrVUOZ9UY?p=preview)

Comment: Don't run filters from the DOM

Comment: Thank you @Jax your plunkr does exactly what i need, just wondering why in $scope.search = function(row)... you give row as argument, what is it?

Comment: It's just a reference to the _element_ you want to filter. You may call it _whatever_ you want ;-) , see answer below for more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I understand you want:

```
<div>
  <table id="results" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>ML</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="name in names | filter: search ">
        <td id="firstName">{{name.firstName}}</td>
        <td id="lastName">{{name.lastName}}</td>
        <td id="ManageList">{{name.ManageList}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

and your JS file

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
'use strict';
    $scope.names = [
      {"id": 11,
       "firstName": "Henry", 
       "lastName": "Durand", 
       "ManageList": "Cocou"}, 
      {
       "id": 12,
       "firstName": "John", 
       "lastName": "Durorn", 
       "ManageList": "Cunoe"                    
      }
    ];
    $scope.search = function (r) {
        return (angular.lowercase(r.firstName).indexOf(angular.lowercase($scope.query) || '') !== -1 ||
                angular.lowercase(r.ManageList).indexOf(angular.lowercase($scope.query) || '') !== -1);
    };
```

As for you question about passing `row` to the `search` function, well it is just a reference to the element you want to filter, you *may* call it whatever you want.

**Here is an updated** [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6we56atrNp5l0LfjDoXd?p=preview)

Also [here's](https://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/) a very good post about Angular filters.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to apply your filters on controller level, view level filters are always slow down your performance. Create filters and use them as dependency in your controller.

```
angular.module('APP').filter('CustomFilterName', ['$filter', function (filter) {
  return function output(data) {
    // filter operations
    return data; // after filtering
  };
}]);

angular.module('APP').controller('ControllerName', ['$filter', function(filters) {
  filters.CustomFilterName(data);
}])
```

Comment: Yes. Its true. Try to call filters at controller level. Otherwise, it will run on each digest cycle.

Comment: But the purpose is to create a Dynamic search: field empty all user are displayed, and while i am typing the number of user displayed change. If i call the filter into the controller, it won't do that, right?

Comment: @Damien.Elbs, you still can do that. use ng-keyup="function();" directive and filter your data and reassign it to $scope.